# creating custom android rom

Tags: android

We are developing a medical android app for a hospital. However, the client asked if there is a way to prevent the users (nurses) from being able to use other functionality of the android phones except for the app we will give him. Is this is possible at all?

Thanx

Comment: I think it's possible with this application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.enterprise.dmagent

Answer (score 2):

Aside from rolling your own ROM, you could make your app the home screen and capture all button presses etc, hide the notification bar and generally block the rest of the device's features.

However, this would be an Android anti pattern, and I would recommend against it. Personally, I'd never work for anyone who tries to impose such strict limits on what I do.